# What does simple zero eigenvalue mean?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I was reading the paper

[Dynamical models of tuberculosis and their applications](https://aimsciences.org/journals/pdfs.jsp?paperID=1058&mode=full)

by Castillo-Chavez, Song B. and it says

> " it is clear that the matrix
>   $$
> D_xf=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> -\mu & 0 &-\phi\\
> 0&-(k+\mu)&\phi\\
> 0& k&-(\mu+r+d)
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>   has a ***simple zero eigenvalue***."

But I have found the eigenvalues of $D_xf$ to be
$$\lambda_1=-\mu$$
$$\lambda_2=-\frac{1}{2}k-\mu-\frac{1}{2}r-\frac{1}{2}d-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d^2-2dk+2dr+k^2+4k\phi-2kr+r^2}$$
$$\lambda_3=-\frac{1}{2}k-\mu-\frac{1}{2}r-\frac{1}{2}d+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d^2-2dk+2dr+k^2+4k\phi-2kr+r^2}$$

So, what does ***simple zero eigenvalue*** mean?

Comment: I guess it means that there is exactly one of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ such that $\lambda_i=0$.

Comment: It means that there is one and only one $k$ for which $\lambda_k = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix has a simple zero eigenvalue because of the parameter $\phi$, which is chosen in a particular way, $\phi=\frac{(k+\mu)(\mu+r+d)}{k}$. For any other choice of $\phi$ there won't be a zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

"simple" is an uncommon term that refers to [an eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity). And "zero" means that the eigenvalue is $0$, of course. This implies that exactly one eigenvalue of the given matrix is zero, although for me that property is not immediately clear here.